# mysql strange "duplicate entry" error

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have a problem I don't quite understand. I parse some feeds with Ruby and save their contents in a database. I created a "hash"-column which is the md5-hash of every post url. That column is UNIQUE because I don't want to post anything twice.

It works fine actually:

```
Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '28edb7c2b3cd074d226fc4ae37baedd7' for key 'hash'
```

But the script stops at this point. I don't get that, I know for a fact that using INSERT with PHP always worked like a charm, so if there was duplicate entry it ignored it and went on.

Can anybody help me? Would "INSERT IGNORE" create a double entry or would it just ignore the error message and go on?

Comment: Do you really want to ignore the error? After all two different text might have same hash value and might cause rare errors in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Ruby script needs some [exception handling.](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-exceptions-and-exception-handling/)

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your query so that instead of INSERT INTO it uses

```
REPLACE INTO ...
```

or

```
INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

This way attempting to insert a duplicate key will update the existing record instead of erroring out.

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for more information.

**Update:**

`INSERT IGNORE` not touch your existing data if it encounters a duplicate key. [The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) says:

> You can use REPLACE instead of INSERT
>   to overwrite old rows. REPLACE is the
>   counterpart to INSERT IGNORE in the
>   treatment of new rows that contain
>   unique key values that duplicate old
>   rows: The new rows are used to replace
>   the old rows rather than being
>   discarded.

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors
>   that occur while executing the INSERT
>   statement are treated as warnings
>   instead. For example, without IGNORE,
>   a row that duplicates an existing
>   UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in
>   the table causes a duplicate-key error
>   and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row still is not inserted,
>   but no error is issued.

Comment: brainbug explained that he desn't want duplicates to get into the table so this method is not appropriate. he wants mysql to reject a duplicate row, not update the existing row with new data.

Comment: @fsb: I can't rule out the possibility that you are right, but that's certainly not what I understand from the question. Can you please provide a pointer to the part of the question you find relevant? I read *"That column is UNIQUE because I don't want to post anything twice"* as *"I don't want two rows with the same value in my table"*, but that's about it. Thanks.

Comment: brainbug gave his `hash` column a `UNIQUE` index. That means that she or he wants to be sure that there are no two rows in the table that have the same value of `hash` and gave a clear reason why. Further, brainbug wants it to work like "a charm" as it did in PHP. We can deduce that behavior: mysqld returns an error on a duplicate insert, the PHP script does not exit on that error, it discards that row and moves on. Using your answer behavior would be very different.

Comment: @fsb: We both know what's happening from a *technical* point of view; I am not quite sure (and you do not justify) what the OP expects from a *functional* point of view. Even so, I updated the answer to include the `INSERT IGNORE` approach even before you posted the first comment here. What else is there to talk about?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, if MySQL returns an error, it doesn't normally kill the PHP script. It sounds to me as though that's not the case in Ruby. Either catch the exception and process it or use INSERT IGNORE, in which case MySQL returns a warning instead of an error (unless it was told not to).

Answer (score 0):

"INSERT IGNORE" Should Prevent Ruby from exiting and shouldn't effect your data. However if you want to know when this is happening you have to put in some error handling.

```
           begin
                DATABASE.query(insertHash)
            rescue
                puts "Error: " + $!.to_s + "Backtrace >>: " + $@.to_s
            end
```

Should show the error with out exiting the ruby script.
Or you could use this to indicate to the user that there is already an entry

Hope this helps